# Port unhexlify from Python 2.7 to Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I'm unfamiliar to Python, and I need to port from 2.7 to 3.5.
In 2.7:

```
>>> unhexlify( '2FE2' )[0]
'/'
```

In 3.5:

```
>>> unhexlify( '2FE2' )[0]
47
```

I've tried using:

```
>>> str(unhexlify( '2FE2' ))[0]
'b'
```

or:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('2FE2')[0]
47
>>> decode_hex('2FE2')[0][0]
47
```

I just can't get the correct ascii. I bump into the representation Python uses: b'... or always getting an int

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`unhexlify` returns a `bytes` object, and indexing into a `bytes` object produces an integer in Python 3 (a `bytes` object holds a sequence of integers in the range 0-255).

If you wanted to get another `bytes` object, use slicing instead:

```
unhexlify('2FE')[:1]
```

This works in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: From what I see, Python 3 adds in the object the "type" on index 0, thus the "b" identifying a byte array. Is my understanding correct? If so, why, makes no sense to me.
Slicing is just removing the "b"? I'm confused

Comment: @TheSingularity_: you are getting confused with string literal notations. You can create a `bytes` object with the `b'...'` literal notation, so `bytes([102, 111, 111])` and `b'foo'` produce the same value. When you use `repr()` or `str()` on such an object (or echo it in the Python interactive interpreter or use `print()` on one, which use `repr()` and `str()` respectively), then Python produces the `b'....'` syntax again for you so you can easily reproduce that value. Just copy the output, paste it into Python code, and you have the same thing again.

Comment: @TheSingularity_: all that is *syntax* however. Slicing works on the *value*, not the syntax. The `b` and the quotes are not part of the value. So `bytesobject[:1]` will create a new `bytes` object with the bytes indicated by the slice. For `b'foo'` that returns `b'f'`, that first byte.

Comment: @TheSingularity_: there are a few other string literal notations that use different prefixes, see the [reference documentation on string and bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).